# cisco route-map using details

Tags: cisco, routing, switching

I can't understand some details of route-map working.

Example:
on interface vlan_A I use route-map_A, on interface vlan_B - route-map_B.

When host from vlan_A send packet to host from vlan_B what route-maps applied to packet:
just route-map_A or route-map_A and route-map_B?

In other words: route-map on vlan interface aplied on all traffic going through interface or just on traffic going from vlan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Route-maps applied to an interface are always applied in the `incoming` direction, meaning as the packet enters the first L3 interface and is about to get routed. In your example only the route-map `route-map_A` would be applied.

For packets not matching the route-map, normal forwarding will take place. There are usually some restrictions as well for PBR such as:

- Correct SDM template
- Only unicast packets are subject to PBR
- No deny statements allowed in route-map
- Software must support it such as IP services
- VRF and PBR on interface are mutually exclusive

An example of configuration and restrictions for the Catalyst 3560 is available [here.](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750x_3560x/software/release/15-0_2_se/configuration/guide/3750x_cg/swiprout.html#wp1228588)

Comment: For net newbies who stumble upon this answer later, please clarify the direction of "incoming".